# Seasonal Reservation system Day/month

Tags: php, date

I am kinda new at php and stuck for few days already at this point, at reservation problem, $ddate is specific date in format of (yyyy/mm/dd).

list($yyear, $mmonth, $dday) = explode('/', $ddate);   // this explodes date in to year month and day. 
What i need it to do is when the actual months of season Winter or Summer are in this date it does reservation for all weeks and all months in that specific day. Reservation is just input in DB, it already works, but question is how to make it count right days when to reserve.

```
$season_type='';
    if ($mmonth = 10 or 11 or 12 or 01 or 02 or 03 or 04) {
    $seson_type='Wint';

    }
    if ($mmonth = 05 or 06 or 07 or 08 or 09) {
    $seson_type='Summ';
```

Example: Winter season is from months 10  to 04 so 7 months, my reservation starts from ($ddate), in this case it is 2014/02/03 so year 2014, month 02, and day 03, and it would be monday, what i need is that now it reservates all mondays in month (02 03 04). I tried to explain it as i could. P.s sorry for any mistakes in grammar. I am just stuck at this point and dont know how to make it work.

Comment: Your currently assigning not comparing. = means assign, == or === means compare

Comment: Thanks, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution would be to use the loop, where you are adding 7 days to date, until you reach the next season:

```php
$your_input_date = '2014/02/03';

$season = [
    'summer' => [5,6,7,8,9],
    'winter' => [10,11,12,1,2,3,4],
];
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y/m/d', $your_input_date);
$is_winter = in_array($dt->format('n'), $season['winter']);
while (in_array($dt->format('n'), $season[$is_winter ? 'winter' : 'summer'])) {
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d'), "\n";
    $dt->modify('+7 day');
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/225816)</kbd>